# How to overwrite style sheets for embedded Tweets

Tags: html, css, twitter

I am trying to overwrite [CSS for embedded Tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets/css). For example I just tried to change `font-size`, but it doesn't work.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/won0jj7c/)

**css**

```
twitterwidget, blockquote, .Tweet, blockquote.Tweet, .twitter-tweet, twitterwidget.twitter-tweet, p, blockquote p, blockquote.Tweet p, twitterwidget.twitter-tweet p{
  font-size: 26px !important;
}
```

Comment: You can to do this with pure CSS, since the content comes from iframe

Comment: Sry, but the comment can't be edited after 5 mins. I meant you `CAN NOT`  apply style for content that comes within an iframe with pure CSS.

Comment: @JavaEvgen I see. Does it mean their documentation is wrong? Why they say it is possible, if it's not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation you linked to, it seems you can change the styling of the fallback presentation, but not the fully styled regular version. The regular version is shown using an iframe to which, if I recall correctly, you can't apply styles from the parent page. This is probably by design -- Twitter don't want you to mess with the branding of the embedded content.

Edit: For example, if you disable JavaScript on the linked documentation page, the tweet indeed renders using the fallback markup, and styles such as yours apply.

Comment: What is fallback presentation?

Comment: When you embed a tweet, it's done using a blockquote and a link to some JavaScript which replaces the blockquote with an iframe making the tweet look however Twitter wants it to look. If said replacing using JavaScript fails, the original blockquote remains, and that's what you can change the styling  of.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can overwrite css if I disable JavaScript, but this is not a solution and I don't understand why they don't mention that in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

**In case someone else is searching** 
I have implemented a simple solution in my project recently, you can customize all kinds of styles to have it fit in seamlessly with your website branding. Hope it helps.

```
 jQuery('.twitter-block').delegate('#twitter-widget-0','DOMSubtreeModified propertychange', function() {
    //function call to override the base twitter styles
    customizeTweetMedia();
});

var customizeTweetMedia = function() {

    overrides font styles and removes the profile picture and media from twitter feed
    jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('.timeline-Tweet-media').css('display', 'none');
    jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('img.Avatar').css('display', 'none');
    jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('span.TweetAuthor-avatar.Identity-avatar').remove();

    jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('.timeline-Tweet-text').css('font-size', '12px');
    jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('.timeline-Tweet-text').css('font-family', "'Proxima Nova', lato, sans-serif");

    jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('span.TweetAuthor-screenName').css('font-size', '12px');
    jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('span.TweetAuthor-screenName').css('font-family', "'Proxima Nova', lato, sans-serif");


    //also call the function on dynamic updates in addition to page load
    jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('.timeline-TweetList').bind('DOMSubtreeModified propertychange', function() {
        customizeTweetMedia(this);
    });
}
```

[Link to my complete example](https://codepen.io/nawa101/pen/gJdxLy)